# Create XSD schema from custom XML file

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have XML looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="profile">
      <section name="server1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1, Custom=null" />
      <section name="server2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1, Custom=null" />
      <section name="server3" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1, Custom=null" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <profile>
    <server1>
      <add key="server" value="serverName1" />
      <add key="check" value="0" />
      <add key="user" value="sa" />
      <add key="psw" value="secret" />
      <add key="show" value="1" />
    </server1>
    <server2>
      <add key="server" value="serverName2" />
      <add key="check" value="0" />
      <add key="user" value="sa" />
      <add key="psw" value="secret" />
      <add key="show" value="1" />
    </server2>
    <server3>
      <add key="server" value="serverName3" />
      <add key="check" value="0" />
      <add key="user" value="sa" />
      <add key="psw" value="secret" />
      <add key="show" value="1" />
    </server3>
  </profile>
</configuration>
```

and I would like to create XSD schema for its validation. I have tried it with online XSD generators like https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html with any of 3 types of XSD Design but the problem is that validation will not pass if there is any other number of servers in XML beside 3.

Any help or advice for software or other online XSD generators which can account for this randomness is very much appreciated?

Comment: The reason that the online generators struggle with this, is that it's bad XML design. Just including multiple `<server>...</server>` elements would be more elegant, easier to parse and easier to generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in XSD (other than XSD 1.1 assertions) to say 'the children of this element must be named "server1", "server2", ... "serverN" in order'. XSD is a bit paternalistic like this: it's not designed to describe any XML you might dream up, it's designed to describe well-designed XML. You should drop the digit and call all the elements "server"; or if the digit serves some purpose (e.g. if it's retained after some server elements are deleted from the XML), then make it an attribute value: `<server id="server1".../>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought it might be something like that. So i guess I'll be changing the source code of "my" application.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that [XSD.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) does a pretty good job. This [validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) is also pretty good too. On top of that you could try the XML Tools plugin in Notepad++.

With complex XML documents it's often easier to build them up slowly, so start with a simplified version and then gradually add other parts.

This [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) and this [one](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-xml-schema/index.cfm) are both very good and are definitely worth looking at if you're struggling with xsds.

---

I suggest you have a look at the tutorials and then maybe rethink what you want and restructure your xml accordingly. An obvious first question might be how do server1, server2, and server3 differ? If they're all the same you want three instances of server; if they're different you probably want to capture that somehow in your xml.